# ExecuteSqlCommand with interpolated string results in 'invalid input syntax' error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

According to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions.executesqlcommand?view=efcore-2.1) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql), I should be able to pass an interpolated string to `ExecuteSqlCommandAsync` like this:

```
public async Task DeleteEntries(DateTimeOffset loggedOn) {
    await myContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(
        $"DELETE from log_entry WHERE logged_on < '{loggedOn}';"
    );
}
```

However, it gives me the following error: `Npgsql.PostgresException: '22007: invalid input syntax for type timestamp with time zone: "@p0"'`

1. `loggedOn` is a valid date.
2. Extracting the interpolated string to a temporary variable fixes it, however I am losing input validation for SQL injection attacks.

Am i doing something wrong or is this a bug in EFCore? Using latest EFCore 2.1

Comment: What's the column type of `logged_on`?

Comment: If you are using a EF context why not remove the item using the context instead of doing a execute sql command?

Comment: Don't use quotes around the table and column identifiers.

Comment: If logged_on is of datetime type in the database, then give this a try: `$"DELETE from log_entry WHERE logged_on < { loggedOn };"`

Comment: The interpolation works as expected. You should remove singe quotes enclosing the placeholder, because EF binds a parameter there, so currently you get `'@p0'` (string) instead of `@p0` (parameter value)

Comment: @IvanStoev that was the answer, thank you

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto It is of DateTImeOffset, I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @Matt Because I having to load entities into memory is much less efficient than a direct delete. This table contains many millions of records that need to be deleted each day. Out-of-context deletions is in the backlog of the EFCore team.

Answer (score 2):

As provided by @IvanStoev, the answer was to remove single quotes around the interpolated parameter.

Answer (score 0):

That webpage you refer to, warns you to not have direct values inserted into SQL, that is to use parameters like so:

```
FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogsForUser @user", user)
```

So, adjust it to your needs and have something like:

```
FromSql("DELETE from log_entry WHERE logged_on < @logged_on", loggedOn.ToString("0"))
```

P.S. do not use double quotes `"` for the table names - either use no quotes or wrap them with `[]` as `[log_entry]`.

Comment: The documentation explicitly states that is supports both interpolated string and format with arguments. The problem was that I used single quotes around the interpolated argument.